# Python running out of memory parsing XML using cElementTree.iterparse

Tags: python, memory-management, memory-leaks, elementtree

A simplified version of my XML parsing function is here:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

def analyze(xml):
    it = ET.iterparse(file(xml))
    count = 0

    for (ev, el) in it:
        count += 1

    print('count: {0}'.format(count))
```

This causes Python to run out of memory, which doesn't make a whole lot of sense. The only thing I am actually storing is the count, an integer. Why is it doing this:

[image]

See that sudden drop in memory and CPU usage at the end? That's Python crashing spectacularly. At least it gives me a `MemoryError` (depending on what else I am doing in the loop, it gives me more random errors, like an `IndexError`) and a stack trace instead of a segfault. But why is it crashing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513592/python-is-there-an-xml-parser-implemented-as-a-generator/1513640#1513640 recommends calling `.clear()` on each element when you're done with it to save memory. Presumably this works because cElementTree keeps the previously-returned values in memory otherwise.

Comment: @Wooble You should post that as an answer. Nailed it.

Comment: Also, I've had good success with `lxml`; it has identical (AFAIK) functionality, but is much more memory and time efficient.

Comment: @Oliver `lxml` beats `ElementTree`, but not `cElementTree` when it comes to parsing.

Comment: @Wooble: In all 3 ElementTree implementations, `iterparse()` builds the tree. It is up to the caller to delete unwanted elements.

Comment: Just a note: this issue seems to not affect the memory on my Mac at all, but causes my Ubuntu server to hemorrhage RAM like it's going out of style.

Answer (score 6):

Code example:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree

def getelements(filename_or_file, tag):
    context = iter(etree.iterparse(filename_or_file, events=('start', 'end')))
    _, root = next(context) # get root element
    for event, elem in context:
        if event == 'end' and elem.tag == tag:
            yield elem
            root.clear() # preserve memory
```

Comment: Shouldn't you invoke `clear()` on `elem` as well? Or are you certain that just clearing the root will cause the garbage collector to collect the element as well?

Comment: @hheimbuerger: `root.clear()` is enough. I haven't dig to deep but the memory usage was small when I used it to parse large xml files.