# python cElementTree uses too much memory

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have the following code segment

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as et

fstring = open(filename).read()
tree = et.fromstring(fstring)

for el in tree.findall('tag'):
    do stuff
```

However, fstring is HUGE (~80mbs of data), and I am hiting "Out of memory" error when I try to convert the string to a tree. Is there a way to get around that, perhaps some kind of lazy evaluation of the tree?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I tried using iterparse, and it still gives me MemoryError on the iterparse call. Is there a way to possibly split up the file into multiple chunks and process them one by one?

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with the data, you could just write a sax parser - they're extremely lightweight compared to dom parsers.

Comment: You can use [`iterparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse). Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7699801/396458

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [`iterparse`](http://effbot.org/zone/element-iterparse.htm):

> For example, to parse large files, you can get rid of elements as soon
>   as you’ve processed them:
>
> ```
> for event, elem in iterparse(source):
>     if elem.tag == "record":
>         ... process record elements ...
>         elem.clear()
> ```

Comment: I am getting "MemoryError" on iterparse(source) line :\

Comment: Are you clearing the elements you've visited, or are you letting them accumulate as you're iterating?

Comment: I am calling elem.clear() at end of the for-loop. Also, I am using xml.etree.cElementTree's iterparse, not lxml. I am not sure if that will make any difference.

Comment: The problem is the call to iterparse is giving me memoryerror. The actual for-loop is not being executed yet.

Comment: I changed it to lxml.etree.iterparse, and I get MemoryError on the same line. The stack trace points to iterparse.__init__ and lxml.etree._encodeFilename functions.

Comment: Actually, I was using iterparse wrong. I was passing in the string instead of the filename. However, now my parsing isn't working. I'll try to debug it. Thanks!

Comment: `elem.clear()` might not be enough. You could call [`root.clear()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13261805/4279)