# How to parse a large XML file in python?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, python-2.7

I'm using python version 2.7.* and i need to get youtube playlist. I do it like this:

```
import urllib
from xml.dom import minidom

playlist_xml = str(urllib.urlopen('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PLKwibIpsTqDyV6NgiJmO-x0yKfqWjApwp?v=2').read())
playlist = minidom.parse(playlist_xml)
```

The problem is that i can't parse the result…

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Python/parser.py", line 11, in <module>
    playlist = minidom.parse(playlist_xml)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1914, in parse
    return expatbuilder.parse(file)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 922, in parse
    fp = open(file, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 63] File name too long:
```

Comment: There are ways to parse unmanageably long XML documents as a stream in python but this is not a particularly large document.  How is the parse call failing?  What were you expecting?

Comment: "I can't parse the result" is not a very descriptive statement of the problem.  Have you looked at the xml you're trying to parse?  Does it raise an error?  If so, what is it?  I doubt very much that this has to do with the size of the XML. Youtube's API only allows 50 results to be returned at a time (I think), so the xml shouldn't be that big.

Comment: related to the question title: [Python running out of memory parsing XML using cElementTree.iterparse](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7697710/4279)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`parseString`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#xml.dom.minidom.parseString) method of minidom instead of [`parse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.dom.minidom.html#xml.dom.minidom.parse). While `parseString` parses XML, and accepts a string, `parse` accepts filename_or_file, and fails treating XML content as a file name.

```
playlist = minidom.parseString(playlist_xml)
```